# How can I change the URL of a networked Time Machine backup

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

The network configuration in my house has changed (new router), so my Linux server (where my networked Time Machine folder is housed) has changed.

`tmutil destinationinfo` yields:

```
> ==================================================
Name          : 500GB External
Kind          : Local
ID            : DF1F27B7-137D-4AE1-9BAE-CD4B603B74FC
====================================================
Name          : TimeMachine
Kind          : Network
URL           : afp://tmuser@192.168.0.12/TimeMachine
Mount Point   : /Volumes/TimeMachine-1
ID            : 2F2F2AC7-C4E5-4F2A-9E7F-8642D6BB441B
```

How can I change the 192.168.0.12 to something else without Time Machine thinking that it's a completely new backup target (and not realizing that the existing backup is ours)?

Comment: Modify the (network) settings of one device (the new router) instead of x existing devices...!

Answer (score 4):

Add the new destination as a new disk in the Time Machine System Preferences GUI. The OS is smart enough to figure things out from there due to identity tokens stored on the Mac and on each of its Time Machine destinations.

It may warn you that the "identity" of the new location has changed, approve that if so before continuing to back up.

Time Machine can handle many destinations from one Mac and just picks up from where it left off for the last backup at that specific destination.

Worst case, you have to manually inherit the backup after associating with the new share. See the `tmutil` manual page for details if needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one destination, you can use the `tmutil` command in the Terminal to replace it with a new one. If it's the same device as before just at a new URL, it will automatically figure it all out and re-use the existing backups.

If your remote share doesn't have a password on it, you can run:

```
sudo tmutil setdestination protocol://username@server-address/share-name
```

(where `protocol` is either `smb` or `afp`).

if it does have a password, you can use `-p` and it will prompt you for the password:

```
sudo tmutil setdestination -p protocol://username@server-address/share-name
```

Note that, unless you have configured passwordless sudo, the first prompt will be your local user password for `sudo`, and the second prompt will be the destination password for `tmutil`.

You can also use the `-a` flag to add a destination instead of replacing the existing one. See `man tmutil` for more info.